# ASPNETCOMPILER: Path or file name is too long

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

ASPNETCOMPILER complains about the next error:

```
The specified path, file name, or both are too long.
The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters,
and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.
```

My code still compiles, but the error persists.

Comment: Do you have node_modules inside your site?

Comment: There are some references about node_modules in the code, but they are mostly related to Angular in js files.

Comment: Could you try running `npm dedupe`?

Comment: Yes. But it doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Could you try removing the node_modules? as a test, just to check if that's the folder causing problems